# How to uniformly pimp Akka Stream Flows and Sources?

Tags: akka-stream

I was able to pimp Flows and Sources independently but could not find a way to make the same code work for both.

```scala
implicit class FlowOps[In, Out, M](self: Flow[In, Out, M]) {
  def scan1(f: (Out, Out) => Out): Flow[In, Out, M] = self
    .prefixAndTail(1)
    .flatMapConcat { case (Seq(head), tail) =>
      tail.scan(head)(f)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FlowOpsMat` instead of `Flow`:

```scala
implicit class FlowOps[Out, M](self: FlowOpsMat[Out, M]) {
  def scan1(f: (Out, Out) => Out): FlowOpsMat[Out, M] = self
    .prefixAndTail(1)
    .flatMapConcat { case (Seq(head), tail) =>
      tail.scan(head)(f)
    }
}

//following works:
Source.single(42).scan1(_+_)
Flow[Int].scan1(_+_)
```

note that the return type isn't preserved this way, and instead of `Source`/`Flow`, you'll get `FlowOpsMat`. but this is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: I was able to compile this solution by using `FlowOps[Out, M]` in place of `FlowOpsMat`. However, because the return type isn't preserved, it limits the ability to compose. E.g. this won't compile: `Flow[Int].via(Flow[Int].scan1(_+_))`.

Comment: I experimented with changing `self: FlowOpsMat[Out, M]` to `val self: FlowOps[Out, M]` and `scan1` return type to `self.Repr[Out]` but it does not compile either.